# Using a Select query to change the Value for two tables depending on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, null, case, union

Goal: I want to create a Select query where the result contains all records from both tables, except the time slot. In a addition to this I want to have the condition that if the minutes of parking are 0 or Null the value of the field should be set to -1.

Progress: At the current state I merged the two tables and could set the 0 value to -1. Due to the fact that I am quite new to SQL I couldn´t find a solution for keeping the original values for minutes and integrate the 'When Null Then -1' clause. Many solutions suggest a Update query , but the operation needs to be in a Select result. MYSQL 2017. This is my code so far:

```
Select c.ID, c.status, c.Date, Case When c.Minutes = 0 Then -1 End as Minutes
From Customer_1 as c
Union
Select c1.ID, c1.status, c1.Date, Case When c1.Minutes = 0 Then -1 End as
Minutes
From Customer_2 as c1
```

Original Dataset: I Have two tables with the exact same column names, representing user IDs

Customer_1:

```
ID| Date| Minutes| Time| status
1 | 2019| 3      | 2019| A
2 | 2019| 0      | 2019| A
```

Customer_2:

```
ID| Date| Minutes| Time| status
3 | 2019| Null   | 2019| A
4 | 2019| 0      | 2019| A
```

What the final query should look like:

```
ID| Date| Minutes| status
1 | 2019| 3      | A
2 | 2019| -1     | A
3 | 2019| -1     | A
4 | 2019| -1     | A
```

Any suggestion how build a working query that fulfills the criteria would be much appreciated!

Comment: I fitted the Coalesce statement to both Select statements and it swapped all Null and 0 values to -1, but eliminated the value 3 for the first user. Unfortunatly that is the same problem I had with the task. If I run the operations on the column, I lose the original value of 3. I somehow need an operation that lets the user, which have a value higher than 0, keep their original value.

Comment: I think you're still missing the **ELSE** part of your CASE clause i.e. `Case When Coalesce(c.Minutes, 0) = 0 Then -1 Else c.Minutes End` as noted in Barbaros's answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using `Coalesce()` function and adding `Else` part is needed within your `Case .. When` statement :

```
Select ID, status, Date, Case When Coalesce(Minutes,0) = 0 Then -1 Else Minutes End as Minutes
  From Customer_1 
 Union
Select ID, status, Date, Case When Coalesce(Minutes,0) = 0 Then -1 Else Minutes End
  From Customer_2
```

and using aliases for tables is redundant in this case, since the queries are independent except for `Union`. The alias(`Minutes`) for the second query is also redundant.

Another alternative might be using an `IF` statement along with `COALESCE()` function :

```
Select ID, status, Date, IF(Coalesce(Minutes,0) , Minutes, -1) as Minutes
  From Customer_1 
 Union
Select ID, status, Date, IF(Coalesce(Minutes,0) , Minutes, -1)
  From Customer_2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fd26ec3f62a676e9ed994bd93cdc89bd)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestions really helped out! I might end up using a Join due to the potential of more tables. Have a great day!